# Populate a listview from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate a `ListView` on my Android app from a Firebase Database. I'm using (and subsequent Storage for my images). I'm putting records into the Database no problem, but retrieving the info back and populating my ListView is proving to be tricky. Here's my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adminfeed);

    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://bookstore-30213.firebaseio.com/All_Books");

    final ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_layout);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(AdminFeed.this, bookModelList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("All_Books");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject book = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //something goes wrong here, i think its possibly with the size of the reading
                    Book newBook = new Book();
                    newBook.setTitle(book.getJSONObject("title").getString("title"));
                    newBook.setImageURL(book.getString("imageURL"));
                    newBook.setAuthor(book.getJSONObject("author").getString("author"));

                    // adding event to events array
                    bookModelList.add(newBook);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

It's returning that my 'bookModelList' is empty, but I've no idea why as I'm clearly adding a book to it. Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what you are getting in response object can you add in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference allBooksRef = rootRef.child("All_Books");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Book> bookModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Book book = ds.getValue(Book.class);
            bookModelList.add(book);
        }
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(AdminFeed.this, bookModelList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
allBooksRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Please note, that there is no need to use a `JSONObject` in order to get data from a Firebase database.

Comment: thanks for the response, I get this error though. "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.apple.BookStore.AccountActivity.AdminApplication.AdminFeed$1.onDataChange(AdminFeed.java:93)"

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I have declared the list also inside the method. Does it work now?

Comment: thankyou for the help, seems to be working fine now!! Although the layout is bad but that's another issue, thanks very much!